# Performance of BINARY vs CAST AS BINARY in MySQL

Tags: performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

Using MySQL 5.6.23, I recently changed a prepared statement from:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY column = :boundValue
```

to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(column AS BINARY) = :boundValue
```

According to the [MySQL docs on `BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-binary-op.html):

> BINARY str is shorthand for CAST(str AS BINARY)

So I expected these two prepared statements to have the same run-time performance. However, the `CAST` version was *significantly* slower. I mean orders of magnitude difference.

The query plans are identical:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: table
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6
        Extra: Using where

CREATE TABLE `session_detail_binary` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `column` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `foo` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bar` varbinary(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_column` (`column`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There are about 260k rows in this table.

What's going on here?

**UPDATE:** I believe this was a red herring. At the same time this `SELECT .. WHERE x` runs, there were a lot of `UPDATE .. WHERE x` on the same table and under the same where condition, where "a lot" means 100x more. This suggests to me the row locks were handicapping the selection.

Comment: The final, performant implementation is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = BINARY :boundValue`

Comment: Can you show the `create table` statement? Any chance for the column already being `BINARY` so the first case being no-op whereas the second one being explicit function call?

Comment: @jkavalik Added the table definition, but no the column is defined `varchar`. I believe, though, there were other factors at play and this was just a red herring -- see the OP update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my tests, I do not see a significant difference (full table scan, 6 rows only, like your example):

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do for i in $(seq 1 100000); do echo "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE CAST(c AS BINARY) = 'f';"; done | /usr/bin/time -f "%e" mysql -BN test > /dev/null; done
5.10
4.93
5.00
4.96
4.97
5.21
4.95
5.04
5.00
5.03
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do for i in $(seq 1 100000); do echo "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE BINARY c = 'f';"; done | /usr/bin/time -f "%e" mysql -BN test > /dev/null; done
5.10
5.28
4.84
5.00
5.19
5.17
7.14
5.06
4.86
6.24
```

If the table had more than 6 rows, an index (and therfore, a query plan change) would be helpful, but only if functions are applied to the right side, not to the column name:

```
MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t1 USE INDEX(c) WHERE c = BINARY 'f'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: range
possible_keys: c
          key: c
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t1 USE INDEX(c) WHERE BINARY c = 'f'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t1 USE INDEX(c) WHERE CAST(c AS BINARY) = 'f'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 6
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t1 USE INDEX(c) WHERE c = CAST('f' AS BINARY)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: range
possible_keys: c
          key: c
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've repeated these tests in an environment devoid of additional, significant `UPDATE` on the same table, and they agree with your results. So I conclude the locking effect of the `UPDATE` affected the apparent performance of the `CAST AS BINARY`: when the `WHERE BINARY` data was gathered, no `UPDATE` were happening.

Comment: Fast: 'WHERE string_column = BINARY ?' and Slow: 'WHERE BINARY string_column = ?'